# ASP.net error INSERTING INTO SQL table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Okay I've come to an point where I have no idea what to do anymore, I've posted a question before and the result was a -3 in votes to close down the question, and in fear of that happening again kept me searching the  googleing till snapped... I've tried numerous code and every single time i get an error...

I've created a database about 6/7 times today and kept changing the connection string...

I've got a database with 3 tables, 1 table is called `Company`, now what I wanna do is I want to use 2 textboxes representing `CompName` and password and a dropdownlist representing businesstype.

I want to use these to enter information into the table, can someone please help me

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class CompanyLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConncetionString"].ConnectionString;

        string sql = "INSERT INTO company (CompName, BusinessType, Pword) VALUES('" + txtCompName.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "', '" + txtPassword + "')";
        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlconn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlconn))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

on line:

```
string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConncetionString"].ConnectionString;
```

`web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="Varsity_College.tempsConnectionString" 
          connectionString="Data Source=JAUN-   PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Varsity_College.temps;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
       ...... (irrelevant) ......
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My error keeps POINTING TO

> *Line 17:*
>   *string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;**

Comment: use a parameterized query, not sql injection

Comment: Can we see the web.config?  Looks like the error will be there, as ConnectionStrings["MyConncetionString"] is probably null

Comment: Cut strait to the point.  If you are trying to fix an error, put it at the top, skip the story about your last post.  Your excpetion indicates that you did not define `MyConnectionString` in the connectionStrings tag in Web.config.  For example `<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLServerNameOrIP;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=user;password=****;Network=IDontKnow" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Answer (score 4):

You have mismatch

MyConncetionString => replace with `MyConnectionString`

You can use

```
   cmd.CommandText =  "insert into company(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) Values(@CompName,@BusinessType,@Pword);"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName", txtCompName.Text);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessType",DropDownList1.Text);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pword",txtPassword );    

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: @Night Programmer You should defensibility use this suggestion as it is implementing a parameterized query. which is the only way to go unless you have a very good reason not to. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass it the entire Password textbox.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO company (CompName, BusinessType, Pword) VALUES('" +    txtCompName.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "', '" + txtPassword + "')";
```

Should be `txtPassword.Text` or `txtPassword.Password` if you're using a password field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the connection string you're trying to load doesn't exist.

Do you have a typo here `MyConncetionString`? (Maybe it's `MyConnectionString`)

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string in `web.config` is called:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Varsity_College.tempsConnectionString"  ..... />
```

So then this line of code will obviously **not** find any connection string in the `web.config`:

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConncetionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Therefore, this expression is `NULL`:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConncetionString"]
```

and attempting to access the `.ConnectionString` property on that `NULL` expression causes the error you're seeing.

These names need to line up!

So use this instead:

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Varsity_College.tempsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

and ***then*** you should get the connection string defined in your `web.config` into your C# code!

Also: it's good principle to **always** check stuff that can be null - e.g.:

```
string ConnectionString = string.Empty;

// get the entry from the config file
var entry = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConncetionString"];

// **CHECK** if entry is NOT NULL ......
if (entry != null)
{
   // only when sure that it's not NULL - **THEN** access the entry....
   ConnectionString = entry.ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you need to add the ConnectionStrings tag inside the configuration tags in your web.config.

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLServerNameOrIP;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=user;password=****;Network=IDontKnow" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Some references which may (or may not) be useful:
[Sample asp.net connection string for web.config](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=webconfig%20connectionstrings%20example&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a317/sample-aspnet-connection-string-for-webconfig.aspx&ei=bSJ3UMm7J4W7iwL2roDwCw&usg=AFQjCNHT6ibTL2hqcg7m1BWDGV1CUbcGog)
[How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Edit:
This looks like a better link: [Storing Database Connection String in Web.Config](http://www.marten-online.com/net/storing-database-connection-string-in-webconfig.html)